# How can I discover what all jars are on my classpath in Java 11 to resolve a duplicate class issue?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to use VS Code to run some unit tests in my solution. When I do, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.mockito.internal.progress.MockingProgress org.mockito.internal.progress.ThreadSafeMockingProgress.mockingProgress()'
at org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.reportMatcher(ArgumentMatchers.java:1330)
at org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq(ArgumentMatchers.java:908)
```

When I run it using maven, I do not get said error. I have two theories. Either the IDE's test runner pulls in an older version of mockito or one of my test dependencies has some older mockito code embedded in it and somehow I'm getting lucky when running it from maven.

My thought was to print out the class path and see if there was anything unusual. But it appears that the code samples[1](https://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/24-java-lang/807-how-to-print-classpath.html) I've found on the Internet doesn't seem to work in Java 11. I'm guessing this is due to things changing with the introduction of modules.

So how can I discover what all jars are on my classpath in Java 11 to resolve a duplicate class issue?

Comment: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));`

Comment: I am not familiar with VS Code so I can't tell you how to do it, but I suggest you try to see what command line it uses to run your java code. The command should contain the class path (or module path).

Comment: Thanks @JohannesKuhn! That seemed to work. And it proved my theory. That for some reason VSCode is throwing in some extra jars that is screwing things up.  I'm wondering if it's internal project format holds on to old jars rather than syncs with maven. But that's a whole different topic. 